# Google Colab Tensorflow 1.15 GPU

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Does anyone know if Google Colab's GPUs are only compatible with tensorflow versions 2.x? I'm trying to run tensorflow 1 code, so I am pip installing tensorflow 1.15, also pip installing tensorflow 1.15 gpu, and changing my notebook settings to enable GPU, however I don't seem to see the GPU speed up effects?

Comment: put `%tensorflow_version 1.x` this in first cell and run before running any cell.

Comment: Thank you, I did that, however it still doesn't seem to utilize the GPU. All I did was run my file with %tensorflow_version1.x on the top, and edited my notebook setting to utilize GPU hardware. Do you know if there is anything extra id need to do?

Comment: Did you changed your runtime type

Comment: Yes, I changed it to run on GPU, yet it is still not.

Comment: you need to install an older version of Cuda and TensorFlow GPU. I tried several times but never succeed .